# Which partition is the CentOS Operating System location?

Tags: partitioning, centos

When I install the CentOS6 operating system, there will create `/boot`, `/`, and `swap` partitions.

[image]

I want to know which partition is the operating system location?
such as if the CentOS OS break down, I can re-install the OS to that partition. like Windows, the C direction is OS location we can re-install the OS to the C, the D, E, F will not loss data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux drive notation is fundamentally different to Windows, and cannot easily be compared.

In your case, the all the OS files are stored in various places on the / (noted as centos-root). The /boot area stores all the files needed to simply load the basics of the OS, and get it running. I'm not sure from the screenshot if it's in a different partition on the physical disk or not.

The swap partition is the Linux equivalent to windows swap file/virtual memory.

In Linux ALL partitions and drives are 'mounted' under the 'root' (/) of the system.